# Watch in directive triggering from outside scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a combobox directive to replace select boxes. Its working pretty well when I only have one select box on a page, but I'm having trouble once I have more than one on a page. Triggering anything that opens the dropdown of the combobox opens up ALL the comboboxes on the page. When I commented out the watch on the page, it starts working as expected. The problem is that I can't figure out why the watch would be triggering outside the scope. I thought that an isolate scope meant its local only to that directive?

The combobox code: http://pastebin.com/MWvXwUdf

Combobox template: http://pastebin.com/DQp0q1Dd

(I'll setup a jsfiddle or plnkr tonight)

How the combobox is called:

```
<combobox data="levels" value="cb_value" search="data.level" strict></combobox>
```

Where `data` is what gets populated in the dropdown, `search` is what goes in the search input, and `value` is what is the returned value.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with the error, here is my version but I'm missing the directive template: https://jsfiddle.net/r8mvo0yb/

Comment: Eeer... good point, I should have done that. I'll setup a jsfiddle sometime tonight when I get home.

Comment: In your combobox directive, the `$combobox` var is global (it misses a `var` statement) - wouldn't it be a problem ?...